# Replicate a POST request with Python or browser

Tags: python, html, post, get, python-requests

So there's this Brazil's government website (https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx) with a consult button ("Consultar") that sends this POST request:

```
Request URL: https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/ListarDocumentos
Request Method: POST
Payload: { dataDe: '', dataAte: '' , empresa: '', tipoDocumento: '-2', dataReferencia: '', categoria: '-1', tipo: '-1', 
especie: '-1', periodo: '0', horaIni: '', horaFim: '', palavraChave:'',ultimaDtRef:'false', tipoEmpresa:'0'}
```

And returns this JSON in response:

```
{"d":{"__type":"Bovespa.Formularios.Shell.Presenters.RetornoTelaGerenciadorDocumento","temErro":false,
"expirouSessao":false,"msgErro":"","dados":"02504-6$&D1000 VAREJO FARMA PARTICIPAÇÕES S.A.$&Dados Eco
...
```

I'm trying to create a Python's code that send a request to get the response above.

```
import requests

payload = { 'dataDe': '', 'dataAte': '' , 'empresa': '', 'tipoDocumento': '-2', 'dataReferencia': '', 'categoria': '-1', 'tipo': '-1', 'especie': '-1', 'periodo': '0', 'horaIni': '', 'horaFim': '', 'palavraChave':'','ultimaDtRef':'false', 'tipoEmpresa':'0'}
r = requests.post("https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/ListarDocumentos", params=payload, verify=False)

print(r.text)

# Tried with JSON Decoder as well but no success
# data=r.json()
# print(data)
```

But this returns the HTML content of the webpage, instead of the desired response. Same result if I change "requests.post" to "requests.get".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><link href="App_Themes/CVM/Calendar/Skins/CVM/Calendar.css"
...
```

I tried to send a GET request as well in browser, but no success:

```
https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/ListarDocumentos?dataDe=&dataAte=&empresa=&tipoDocumento=-2&dataReferencia=&categoria=-1&tipo=-1&especie=-1&periodo=0&horaIni=&horaFim=&palavraChave=&ultimaDtRef=false&tipoEmpresa=0
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json=` parameter in `requests.post()` to get the data:

```
import json
import requests


payload = { 'dataDe': '', 'dataAte': '' , 'empresa': '', 'tipoDocumento': '-2', 'dataReferencia': '', 'categoria': '-1', 'tipo': '-1', 'especie': '-1', 'periodo': '0', 'horaIni': '', 'horaFim': '', 'palavraChave':'','ultimaDtRef':'false', 'tipoEmpresa':'0'}
r = requests.post("https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/ListarDocumentos", json=payload, verify=False)
data = r.json()

# print to screen:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__type": "Bovespa.Formularios.Shell.Presenters.RetornoTelaGerenciadorDocumento",
        "temErro": false,
        "expirouSessao": false,
        "msgErro": "",
        "dados": "02504-6$&D1000 VAREJO FARMA PARTICIPA\u00c7\u00d5ES S.A.$&Dados Econ\u00f4mico-Financeiros$&Press-release$&<spanOrder>Divulga\u00e7\u00e3o de 

...
```