# Difficult to send JSON httr POST request

Tags: r, json, post, httr

I'm having difficulties trying to send a JSON POST using HTTR package. It´s exactly the same problem presented on [Replicate a POST request with Python or browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455535/replicate-a-post-request-with-python-or-browser), but this time on R.

```
url <- "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/ListarDocumentos"
payload <- list(
    dataDe= '', 
    dataAte= '' , 
    empresa= '', 
    setorAtividade= '-1', 
    categoriaEmissor= '-1', 
    situacaoEmissor= '-1', 
    tipoParticipante= '-1', 
    dataReferencia= '', 
    categoria= 'EST_3', 
    periodo= '1', 
    horaIni= '', 
    horaFim= '', 
    palavraChave='',
    ultimaDtRef='false', 
    tipoEmpresa='0'
)
```

This returns a JSON response different from what I obtain using the follow POST request:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
   
r <- POST( url = url,
           body = toJSON(payload, auto_unbox = T))
```

This request returns the HTML content of the webpage, instead of the desired response.

```
    {html_document}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
[1] <head id="Head1">\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<link href="App_Themes/CVM/Calend ...
[2] <body>\r\n    <form name="Form1" method="post" action="frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx" id="Form1">\r\n<input type="hidden" na ...
```

I've tried many combinations using different forms of writting the request payload and using those terms inside POST request:

```
    httr::content_type_json()
    httr::accept_json()
    encode = "json"
```

But anything seems to work. I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you pass the parameters (`payload` values) via URL?. Something like `https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/ListarDocumentos/dataDe= ''&dataAte= ''......`

Comment: It doesn't work, receive a "Bad Request".